# Drawing a variable number of textures

Tags: webgl

For some scientific data visualization, I am drawing a large float array using WebGL. The dataset is two-dimensional and typically hundreds or few thousands of values in height and several tens of thousands values in width.

To fit this dataset into video memory, I cut it up into several non-square textures (depending on `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`) and display them next to one another. I use the same shader with a single `sampler2d` to draw all the textures. This means that I have to iterate over all the textures for drawing:

```
for (var i=0; i<dataTextures.length; i++) {
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0+i);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, dataTextures[i]);
    gl.uniform1i(samplerUniform, i);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBuffers[i]);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

However, if the number of textures gets larger than half a dozen, performance becomes quite bad. Now I know that games use quite a few more textures than that, so this can't be expected behavior. I also read that you can bind arrays of samplers, but as far as I can tell, the total number of texture has to be known ahead of time. For me, the number of textures depends on the dataset, so I can't know it before loading the data.

Also, I suspect that I am doing unnecessary things in this render loop. Any hints would be welcome.

How would you normally draw a variable number of textures in WebGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few previous answers that will help

[How to bind an array of textures to a WebGL shader uniform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592850/how-to-bind-an-array-of-textures-to-a-webgl-shader-uniform/19610642#19610642)

[How to send multiple textures to a fragment shader in WebGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755320/how-to-send-multiple-textures-to-a-fragment-shader-in-webgl/19760061#19760061)

[How many textures can I use in a webgl fragment shader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836102/how-many-textures-can-i-use-in-a-webgl-fragment-shader/20850584#20850584)

Some ways off the top if my head

1. Create a shader that loops over N textures. Set the textures you're not using to some 1x1 pixel texture with 0,0,0,0 in it or something else that doesn't effect your calculations
2. Create a shader that loops over N textures. Create a uniform boolean array, in the loop skip any texture who's corresponding boolean value is false.
3. Generate a shader on the fly that has exactly the number of textures you need. It shouldn't be that hard to concatinate a few strings etc..

Comment: Is it a common practice to generate shader code programmatically? This seems rather hacky to me.

Comment: Yes, you can look through the three.js code and see it generates shaders. A typical AAA game may generate 4000+ shaders. Sometimes it's easier to use an *uber* shader (option #2 above) but it's slower to execute than generating a shader that does exactly what you need. Games typically generate them at compile time because they know what shaders they will need when they ship (the artists have finished making all the assets). If you don't know ahead of time though then generating them on the fly is the normal thing to do.

Comment: As long as you can generate the shaders at a time where you dont have any latency issues, its fine. Remember, that it takes many frames to compile and push a new program/shaders on the GPU. Once its there, its kinda cheap to change the useProgram..

Comment: For example, its kinda good to recompile shaders for each user setting. If user turns of lights completly for example, once can use more lightweight shaders and remove a few conditions maybe. If you wouldnt do so, performance might be the same both with lights turned on and off as the condition would still be checked all the time, though it would never become true.